# Couchbase backup validation

Tags: database-design, backup, nosql, couchbase

Need help regarding backup validations for couchbase, what is the best way / easiest way to validate couchbase backups.

we have recently moved to couchbase and totally new to couchbase, having some trouble with backup validation.

we are using **cbbackupmgr** backup for taking backup's and tar the backup file at the end, could not find any solution on my research.

Any help from this community, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question related to Microsoft SQL Server in some way? If not, remove the `sql-server` tag.

Comment: update @DanGuzman, Thanks thought it will get more visibility from other groups.